# Custom compile time variables for use in Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, constants

Is there a way to tell XCode to insert certain variables or constants into your project at compile time, for you to use in your code? Specifically, I'm talking about iOS projects, so I don't have the option to use command line arguments, I think.

Why would I need this, you ask? Well say that for certain cells in a table view, I'd like to add a different subtitle text, because it helps me pick the right cell during development. Something like this would be awesome:

```
if (MY_COMPILE_TIME_BOOL_CONST) {
    cell.subtitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Contains %i items", count];
} else {
    cell.subtitle.text = @"";
}
```

But there are lots of other places this would come in handy. Somehow, when trying to google the answer, I only get to "beginning with XCode tutorials".

Can anyone point towards the magic?

UPDATE: The magic word to google for is "preprocessor macro". Thanks, SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start your app from XCode you can totally use command line arguments.

You could also add something like `DEBUG=1` to the preprocessor macro for the debug configuration. Then you can add preprocessor ifs into your code and the corresponding code will only be compiled in Debug mode.

```
#if DEBUG
NSLog(@"Foo");
#endif
```

The latter is what I use every day.

Comment: See, I was googling "compile time constants" where what I was actually looking for was "preprocessor macro". This works exactly the way I want it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to add one or more header files for these macros try the steps below.

In Xcode, double click the *target*, select the *Configuration* (Debug/Release/etc) you want your special defines in. Then type *preprocessor*" in the search field. Then you should see **Preprocessor Macros** where you can enter your *extras*.

Answer (score 0):

what about :

```
#define DEBUG YES
```

in your `.pch`

then you could do something like

```
if (DEBUG) {
   cell.subtitle.text = @"Counting xyz";
   return cell;
}

cell.subtitle.text = @"";
return cell;
```

if youre mainly developing in simulator you could also check for simulator.

Comment: Ah yes, that was my first idea too, but I'm working in a team and would like to link the constants to the active configuration (debug/release/distribution)